# MVC 5 with two registration forms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Is it possible or even recommended to create 2 registration forms for the same application? I am using ASP.NET Identity 2.0 for this project. Both registration forms have similar field names but have different purpose. One is for Teacher Training and the other is for Donations.  Would it be better to create two separate applications?

Example First Registration Form

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register1(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
          var user = new ApplicationUser 
           { 
            UserName = model.Email, 
            Email = model.Email 
              };

        // Add the Address properties:
        user.Address = model.Address;
        user.City = model.City;
        user.State = model.State;
        user.PostalCode = model.PostalCode;
        // Additional fields specific to Registration Form1
        field1
        field2
        .....

        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
            var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", 
                new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
            await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, 
                "Confirm your account", 
                "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" 
                + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");
            ViewBag.Link = callbackUrl;
            return View("DisplayEmail");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Second Registration Form

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register2(RegisterViewModel model)
     {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
          var user = new ApplicationUser 
           { 
            UserName = model.Email, 
            Email = model.Email 
              };

        // Add the Address properties:
        user.Address = model.Address;
        user.City = model.City;
        user.State = model.State;
        user.PostalCode = model.PostalCode;
        // Additional fields specific to Registration Form2
        field1
        field2
        SiteURL
        PaymentType

        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
            var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", 
                new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
            await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, 
                "Confirm your account", 
                "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" 
                + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");
            ViewBag.Link = callbackUrl;
            return View("DisplayEmail");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible or even recommended to create 2 registration forms for the same application?

**Yes**, it is possible.

> Would it be better to create two separate applications?

There is **no** need to create separate applications - just provide the underlying structure and logic for business and DB so the input from forms would be processed accordingly.

Comment: The content for both registration forms will be stored in the AspNetUsers profile table? 

Do you any sample code that can get me started? I am not sure how to go about it.

Comment: @ceci See some examples here: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/data/5-working-with-data

Comment: thanks for the link. But this looks like introduction to DBs and doesn't help me figure it out how to incorporate two registrations forms using the existing RegisterViewModel model.